# SVG circle bouncing on rotation

Tags: html, css, svg, rotation, css-transforms

If you look closely you can see the circle bounce up and down in the below code snippet:

```css
svg {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

img {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
     from {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
     }
     to {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" height="15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="500"/>
</svg>
```

The effect is more obvious if you zoom in, and is also worse if the height is set to an odd number of pixels. Why does it do this? And how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: I see no bouncing at all even when I zoom in. Perhaps it's a bug in your specific browser/platform/graphics card.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've managed to reproduce the problem on various different browsers and computers

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any bouncing either.  But perhaps you will have more luck if you just rotate the circle, rather than the whole `<svg>` element.  Is this any better?

```css
svg circle {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
     from {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
     }
     to {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" height="15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="500"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately the circle still seems to be rotating off-centre.

Comment: Well then you will need to update your question with more detail. What OS and browser versions are you using? Is there anything special about your computer, graphics card, etc?  No-one else has reported seeing the same thing with your example.

Answer (score 1):

- added a bi-color gradient to **@Paul LeBeau**'s answer to show the
  rotation of the circle
- added a frame with which you can see the absence of beating of the   circle's during rotation

```css
svg circle {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  fill:url(#Lg);
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
     from {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
     }
     to {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
     }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid" >
   <defs>
     <linearGradient id="Lg" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
       
      </linearGradient> 
   </defs>
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="500"/>
</svg>
```